# C sentinel loop question

Tags: c, while-loop

This program is supposed to judge the height of multiple buildings by the type of building and number of stories. There is a loop that continues to ask the questions until the user enters "0" for type of building. At the end, it prints a report showing the types of buildings and how many of each conform to building codes. I am having problems compiling the program, but I'm not sure if the loop is right either.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
//constants
#define MIN_HEIGHT 180
#define MAX_HEIGHT 220
#define ROOF_MULT 2.0

int main()
{
    //variables
    int type, stories, F_TO_MECH, osum, rhsum, msum;
    double height, ADD_MECH_HEIGHT, code, F_HEIGHT;
    osum=0, rhsum=0, msum=0;


    //Find type of building and number of stories.
    printf("Enter a building type (1=Office, 2=Residential/Hotel, 3=Mixed-Use, 0=Stop): ");
    scanf("%d", &type);
    printf("Enter the number of stories in the building: ");
    scanf("%d", &stories);


    //Switch to differentiate constants of building types.
    while (type != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            switch (type) //Switch for building constants.
            {
                case 1:     F_HEIGHT=3.9;
                            ADD_MECH_HEIGHT=2.0;
                            F_TO_MECH=20;
                            break;

                case 2:     F_HEIGHT=3.1;
                            ADD_MECH_HEIGHT=1.55;
                            F_TO_MECH=30;
                            break;

                case 3:     F_HEIGHT=3.5;
                            ADD_MECH_HEIGHT=1.75;
                            F_TO_MECH=25;
                            break;
            }

            //Formula to find height.
            height = (stories * F_HEIGHT) + ((F_HEIGHT * ROOF_MULT) + ADD_MECH_HEIGHT) + (ADD_MECH_HEIGHT * (stories / F_TO_MECH));


            if( height <= MAX_HEIGHT )
            {
                if( height >= MIN_HEIGHT )
                {
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case 1: osum = osum++;

                        case 2: rhsum = rhsum++;

                        case 3: msum = msum++;
                    }
                }
            }
                printf("Enter a building type (1=Office, 2=Residential/Hotel, 3=Mixed-Use, 0=Stop): ");
                scanf("%d", &type);
                printf("Enter the number of stories in the building: ");
                scanf("%d", &stories);

        } //End While statment.
    //print results.
    printf("Building Type   Count \n-------------------\nOffice         %3.0f\nRes/Hotel      %3.0f\nMix-Use        %3.0f\n", osum, rhsum, msum;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error I get when I try to compile:
assign04.c:79: error: expected â€˜whileâ€™ before â€˜printfâ€™
assign04.c:82: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated:

```
int main()
{
//variables
int type, stories, F_TO_MECH, osum, rhsum, msum;
double height, ADD_MECH_HEIGHT, F_HEIGHT;
osum=0, rhsum=0, msum=0;

//Find type of building
printf("Enter a building type (1=Office, 2=Residential/Hotel, 3=Mixed-Use, 0=Stop): ");
scanf("%d", &type);

//Switch to differentiate constants of building types.
do
{
    //find the number of stories.
    printf("Enter the number of stories in the building: ");
    scanf("%d", &stories);

    switch (type) //Switch for building constants.
    {
        case 1: F_HEIGHT=3.9;
                    ADD_MECH_HEIGHT=2.0;
                    F_TO_MECH=20;
                    break;

        case 2:     F_HEIGHT=3.1;
                    ADD_MECH_HEIGHT=1.55;
                    F_TO_MECH=30;
                    break;

        case 3: F_HEIGHT=3.5;
                    ADD_MECH_HEIGHT=1.75;
                    F_TO_MECH=25;
                    break;
    }

    //Formula to find height.
    height = (stories * F_HEIGHT) + ((F_HEIGHT * ROOF_MULT) + ADD_MECH_HEIGHT) + (ADD_MECH_HEIGHT * (stories / F_TO_MECH));


    if( height <= MAX_HEIGHT )
    {
        if( height >= MIN_HEIGHT )
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1: osum = osum++;

                case 2: rhsum = rhsum++;

                case 3: msum = msum++;
            }
        }
    }

} while (type != 0); //End While statment.

//print results.
printf("Building Type   Count \n-------------------\nOffice         %3.0f\nRes/Hotel      %3.0f\nMix-Use        %3.0f\n", osum, rhsum, msum;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would I need to enter the number of stories on the "Stop" building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A While loop is of the form:

```
while(condition)
{
    body of code
}
```

And a do while is of the form:

```
do
{
    body of code
} while(condition);
```

The difference is that the do while loop guarantees the body of the loop will execute at least once.

The code you posted is a mix of the two. Figure out which type of while loop you need for this particular problem as this appears to be homework.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I believe I've corrected the code, but I'm still getting the error: "assign04.c:74: error: expected â€˜;â€™ before â€˜printfâ€™" while trying to compile.

Comment: @Jesse: that indicates that the compiler is looking for the end of the `do` loop (`while(condition);`), but not finding it. Do you still have a `do` statement? If so, do you have a corresponding `while(condition);`? (note the semicolon!)

Comment: @Jesse: also, please fix the compiler message corruption. We see `expected â€˜;â€™ before â€˜printfâ€™"`. Makes it hard to see what's actually going on.

Comment: I changed the code to the second example above. So there is a do statement, and all of the { are closed.

Comment: ... that's how it's showing up in JGrasp. I'm not really sure how to fix that.

Comment: Do I need to put an "else" statement, even if I don't want anything to happen if the conditions of "if" aren't met?

Comment: @Jesse: no, you don't. Don't take this the wrong way, but... do you have a copy of [K&R](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628)? Maybe step through that, for some of these frankly basic questions.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably go get it. I am doing this for a class, and the teacher assumes alot. She is not much of a teacher, and it's obviously showing. I'm sure I'm just missing some simple character somewhere, but it gets hard to notice stuff like that, when you've been staring at code for a few hours.

Comment: @Jesse: you're missing a closing parenthesis on the last `printf`.

Comment: I understand. Do yourself a favor and go buy that book. It's not only a great way to learn C, it's also 1) one of the best introductory CS textbooks ever written, and 2) really short.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Of course, I missed a ) after the last printf statement. I'm going to buy the book tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your braces are unbalanced; you're missing an end brace.  It looks like you're missing the end of your `do` clause.

Also, note that since your `scanf` statements are outside of any loop, your question will only be asked once. You'll need to ask the user *inside* a loop. You can also, most likely, avoid having two nested (the `do` and the `while`) loops; one should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (type != 0)
{
    do
    {
```

I don't see a `} while (condition);` that corresponds to the `do`.

Also, it's unrelated to your compilation error, but you should avoid using `scanf` unless you know what you're doing: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html